# Is completion of isolated singularity isolated?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, completion

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field and let $A=K[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I$ be a $K$-algebra of finite type which has only an isolated singularity at the origin. Let $\mathfrak{m}=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and consider the localization $A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ and its $\mathfrak{m}$-adic completion $B$.

Is $B$ also an isolated singularity? The localization at $\mathfrak{m}$ should not be a problem, but completion might. In general, the completion of an isolated singularity need not to be isolated. However, I was wondering whether in this situation the answer might be positive. I am willing to assume some stronger hypothesis. Can anybody point out any results in this direction?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that in your situation, $B$ indeed has an isolated singularity at the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{n} \subseteq B$. Let me first give two possible definitions for “isolated singularity”; please let me know if there are standard definitions for these notions, and I will edit this answer accordingly!

**Definition.** Let $X$ be a locally noetherian scheme.

1. We say that $X$ has an *isolated singularity* at a closed point $x \in X$ if there is an open neighborhood $U \ni x$ such that the scheme $U \smallsetminus \{x\}$ is regular.
2. Suppose that $X$ is a scheme over a field $k$. We say that $X$ has a *geometric isolated singularity* at a closed point $x \in X$ if there is an open neighborhood $U \ni x$ such that the scheme $U \smallsetminus \{x\}$ is geometrically regular over $k$.

Adopting either definition, the ring $B$ in your situation has a isolated singularity (resp. geometric isolated singularity) at the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{n} \subseteq B$. We can in fact prove the following more general result:

**Proposition.** *Let $X$ be a locally noetherian scheme (resp. locally noetherian scheme over a field $k$) with an isolated singularity (resp. geometric isolated singularity) at a closed point $x \in X$, such that $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is a $G$-ring. Then, $\operatorname{Spec}\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,x}$ has an isolated singularity (resp. geometric isolated singularity) at the unique closed point $\widehat{x}$.*

Note that this proposition applies to your situation, since $A$ is of fintie type over a field, hence a $G$-ring in the sense of [Mat89, p. 256] by [Mat89, Cor. to Thm. 32.6] ($A$ is also excellent, but we only need the $G$-ring part of the definition of excellence).

*Proof.* Let $U \subseteq \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ be the intersection of $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ and a neighborhood of $x$ in $X$ satisfying the condition in the definition above. Let $f\colon \operatorname{Spec} \widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,x} \to \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ be the morphism induced by the completion homomorphism. The morphism
$$f^{-1}(U) \smallsetminus \{\widehat{x}\} \longrightarrow U \smallsetminus \{x\}\tag{1}\label{eq:completion}$$
is regular in the sense of [Mat89, p. 255] since the morphism $f$ is regular by the $G$-ring condition, and regular morphisms are preserved under base change [EGAIV$_2$, Prop. 6.8.3(iii)].

For isolated singularities, we apply [Mat89, Thm. 23.7] to the (localizations of the) morphism \eqref{eq:completion} to conclude that $f^{-1}(U) \smallsetminus \{\widehat{x}\}$ is regular.

For geometric isolated singularities, the composition
$$f^{-1}(U) \smallsetminus \{\widehat{x}\} \longrightarrow U \smallsetminus \{x\} \longrightarrow \operatorname{Spec} k$$
is regular by [Mat89, Thm. 32.1], i.e., $f^{-1}(U) \smallsetminus \{\widehat{x}\}$ is geometrically regular over $k$. $\blacksquare$

#### References

[EGAIV$_2$] Alexander Grothendieck and Jean Dieudonné. “Éléments de géométrie algébrique. IV. Étude locale des schémas et des morphismes de schémas. II.” *Inst. Hautes Études Sci. Publ. Math.* (1965), no. 24, 1–231. DOI: [10.1007/BF02684322](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02684322). MR: [199181](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=199181).

[Mat89] Hideyuki Matsumura. *Commutative ring theory.* Second ed. Translated from the Japanese by M. Reid. Cambridge Stud. Adv. Math. 8. Cambridge Univ. Press, Cambridge, 1989. DOI: [10.1017/CBO9781139171762](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139171762). MR: [1011461](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1011461).

Comment: Dear Takumi, thank you for your nice and precise answer. It looks correct to me. The key point here is really the fact that finitely generated algebras over a field are $G$-rings. I have not thought about it.
Concerning your question about the "standard" definition of isolated singularity. Personally, when I say isolated singularity I mean the first one. Or more algebraically, I say that a local ring $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ has an isolated singularity if $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is regular for any prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\neq\mathfrak{m}$. I am not sure whether this is "standard" or not.

Comment: Dear @Alessio, thank you for the kind words! You are correct that the key point is the $G$-ring condition; I have tried to make this clearer by explicitly stating a result only requiring this condition. Thank you for clarifying the definition of "isolated singularity" as well; my confusion is always that over imperfect fields, I don't know whether "singular" should mean "not regular" or "not smooth".

Comment: You're welcome. I think it really depends whom do you ask to. Being more a commutative algebraist guy I'd like to think "singular" = "not regular", but I guess other people would prefer "not smooth".